# Validating email and username in PDO

Tags: php, mysql, email, pdo

The code below is a registration form in which before inserting data into database we check If username and email is already taken, actually it was written `php` `mysqli` where it worked fine but now I am switching to PDO. The code works fine and data is inserted but it doesn't check email and username, I mean we could insert data again with same email and username. I don't know why isn't it working in this PDO format it worked fine in simple php standard may be because I have not got hands on PDO yet. Please help me. What I want is to check for email and username before inserting data into database and if they are already taken data is not inserted and we get error message.

```
 $exists = "";
 $query = $db->prepare("SELECT COUNT (username) from userss WHERE username = :username ");
 $query->execute(array(':username'=>$un));
 if ($query->fetchAll() == 1) {
 $exists .= "u";
 } 
 $query = $db->prepare("SELECT COUNT (email) from userss WHERE email = :email ");
 $query->execute(array(':email'=>$em));
 if ($query->fetchAll() == 1) {
 $exists .= "e";
 }

 if ($exists == "u") echo "<p><b>Error:</b> Username already exists!</p>";
 else if ($exists == "e") echo "<p><b>Error:</b> Email already exists!</p>";
 else if ($exists == "ue") echo "<p><b>Error:</b> Username and Email already exists!</p>";
  else {

 $stmt = "INSERT INTO userss (username,first_name,last_name,email,password,password2,) 
 VALUES (:username,:first_name,:last_name,:email,:password,:password2,)";
 $query = $db->prepare( $stmt );  
 $query->execute( array(':username'=>$un,':first_name'=>$fn,':last_name'=>$ln,':email'=>$em,
 ':password'=>$pswd,':password2'=>$pswd2,));
 if ($query->rowCount() == 1) {
  header("Location: login.php");
  } 
 else {
 echo "error";
 }
```

Comment: Just out of interest! Why are you hashing the password2 which is the `Confirm Password`? Also why are you storing it on the database? DUH" Thats there just so you can check the user didnt keyin 2 different password i.e. make a keying mistake.

Answer (score 0):

```
$query->fetchAll()
```

Returns an array, so you should check if any data was returned by counting the elements, like so:

```
if (count($query->fetchAll()) > 0)
```

Note that it is testing for greater than zero, in case your database already has duplicates, this will prevent more.

Comment: What isn't working?  Is there an error message?  Is the test failing?

Comment: no error, data is inserted even with already existing username and email, I was supposing to get error message like username and email already taken choose another.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
if ($query->fetchAll() == 1)
```

try:

```
if ($query->fetchColumn() > 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

`$query->fetchAll();` will return multidimensional array, and your query want to return `COUNT`, So make an aliases for count using `AS`, your query should be like

```
 $query = $db->prepare("SELECT COUNT (username) AS user_count from userss WHERE username = :username ");
 $query->execute(array(':username'=>$un));
 if ($query->fetch()['user_count'] > 0) {
 $exists .= "u";
 } 

 $query = $db->prepare("SELECT COUNT (email) AS email_count from userss WHERE email = :email ");
 $query->execute(array(':email'=>$em));
 if ($query->fetch()['email_count'] > 0) {
 $exists .= "e";
 }
```